# Are there any 3NF tables in the MySQL employee sample database?

Tags: database, denormalization, 3nf

I am currently working on a question where I am asked to denormalize any two tables from 3NF to 2NF from the MySQL employees sample database.

My problem is that from the schema I can't determine any 3NF tables. Am I blind? The shema is shown below and is taken from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html) MySQL page.

I would appreciate if somebody could verify that my thinking.. thanks.

[image: 'employees' database schema]

Comment: These all look thirdly-normal to me (given certain reasonable assumptions about the domain, eg that employees can change salary, and can be given the same title twice at different points in time). Why do you think they aren't?

Comment: I just don't see it.. for salaries, how would you change it then? All I can think is that you make `to_date` part of the primary key? It's not that I think they're not I just don't see it. I'm looking for a straight transitive dependency, I can't seem to figure out the business aspect? Thanks for your help.